# Asp.NET Core Path string

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

I'm working in Asp.NET Core in VS 2015.

I'm trying to get the last directory in a URL.

I'm currently using `string path = Context.Request.Path;` which, for example, if I had the URL `localhost.foo.com/bar/3`, it would return `/bar/3`, Is there a way to get the 3 only? The 3 would be an ID for an object in my case.

And if not, is there a better way to return an object's ID that's used in the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your string by `/` and get last element:

```
string path = Context.Request.Path;
var lastValue = path.Split('/').Last();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using route parameters in order to do this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing

If you have the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

your controller function could take in a parameter like:

```
public IHttpActionResult myFunc(int id)
```

If this route template does not fit your exact situation, you could add additional route templates so that the parameters are mapped, or you could add a custom route to the attributes on your function to get the parameters you're looking for.

Comment: I do have route parameters, I've got an IActionResult method in my controller takes two Ids as parameters, I'm just trying to get the Id from the URL to pass them to the method.

Comment: If you have them as route parameters, is there a reason why you cannot just pass them from the controller method that is capturing them.  I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.